# Jasmine: Expected spy <function> to have been called error

Tags: jasmine

In my angular application, I am trying to write a test case for following scenario but getting error 'Expected spy reinvite to have been called.'. Im testing on "jasmine-core: ^2.5.2 and "karma: ^1.3.0". I have written similar test cases and they passed without error.

In my controller file:

```
function reinvite() {

        var emailsToReInvite = $j.map($scope.settingsData.userSettingsDetails, function(user) {
             if(user.reInviteChecked){
                return user.email;  
            }
        });

        if (emailsToReInvite.length >= 1) {

            var invitation = { invitees: emailsToReInvite, listId: listId};
            invitation = JSON.stringify(invitation);

            inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService.reinvite(invitation).then(
                function success(response) {
                    if(response.data.messages[0].code == 214){
                        $scope.showReinviteSuccess = true;

                        }
                    }else{
                        $scope.showReinviteSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

And my spec file:

```
describe('settingsModalController', function() {
var controllerUnderTest = "settingsModalController";    
var controllerResolver, rootScope, injector, $scope, inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService

beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('sharedListApp');

    inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $injector){
        controllerResolver = $controller;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        injector = $injector;
    });

    $scope = rootScope.$new();
    inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService = injector.get('uiCommon.inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService');
});

it("should send re-invitation mail to selected users successfully", shouldReinviteSelectedUsers);

function shouldReinviteSelectedUsers() {
    var $q = injector.get('$q');
    $scope.settingsData = {
        userSettingsDetails: [{email: 'abc@xyz.com'}]
    };
    var data = { 
        messages: [ { code: 214 }],
        invite: {
            invitation: $scope.settingsData
        }
    };
    var response = { data: data };
    var mockResult = new $q.defer();
    mockResult.resolve(response);

    spyOn(inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService, 'reinvite').and.returnValue(mockResult.promise);

    controllerResolver(controllerUnderTest, { $scope: $scope });

    $scope.reinvite();
    $scope.showReinviteSuccess = true;
    $scope.$apply();

    expect(inviteCollaboratorsModalDataService.reinvite).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($scope.showReinviteSuccess).toBe(true);
}
```

}

What am i doing wrong or what am i missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i missed one variable to add in $scope.settingsData in my spec file which was why my spec code was not parsing into the first 'if' loop of the controller. Got it working by adding 'reInviteChecked: true' in:

```
$scope.settingsData = {
    userSettingsDetails: [{email: 'abc@xyz.com', reInviteChecked: true}]
};
```